# How to do full text search with Spring Data and Mongodb with wildcard ?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using mongodb and spring data to do full text search.
If it comes to search whole word/words like "doctor" its works ok, but I also want to get some result when I type "doc", and this is not happening.

```
public List<Link> findAllByKeywords(String keyword) {
        TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(keyword);

        List<Link> links = linkRepository.findByOrderByScoreDesc(textCriteria);

        return links;
  }
```

Is there any function in mongodb like "LIKE" in SQL ?
Any advice is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: Wildcard search in full text is not supported in MongoDB. If you really in need of wildcard, consider regex instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
String firstName = "Jason";
Query query = new Query();
query.limit(10);        
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("firstName").regex(tagName));
mongoOperation.find(query, Names.class);
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit?